# Changing all the heading tags at once using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, json

So I'm using jQuery to concatenate a string to all the heading tags i.e. h1, h2,...., h6 and display it on the screen. I just want help in the replacing part and if you have a solution in plain **javascript**, it will be useful too.

This my code which I'm certain is wrong:

```
        jQuery.noConflict();  
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            
            var heading_text = '$heading_text';
            var page_heading = jQuery('h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6').text();

            //concatenating the two variables
            page_heading.html(page_heading+' '+heading_text);
        });
```

here, `$heading_text` is the input received.
for eg: if  `$heading_text` is **xyz** and text between `h1` tag is  **oh** then after calling out this function, the text between `h1` tag should be ***oh xyz***

Comment: "*using jquery*" ... *"in plain javascript"* - so do you want jquery or not jquery?

Comment: jQuery multiple selector is with the comma inside the quotes, ie `$('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6')`.   Your output is a little confused as well as `page_header` is a string (the combined text) so isn't an output.   Is this what you're looking for?  https://jsfiddle.net/782uLesc/

Comment: @freedomn-m both are okay

Comment: When you say "to all the heading tags" - do you mean to "each of the heading tags" - ie, one by one?  https://jsfiddle.net/782uLesc/1/  If the heading has any other HTML content, using `.text(txt+newtext)` will lose that, so you can use `.append(txt)` and it will append as a child text node:  https://jsfiddle.net/782uLesc/2/  `$('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').append(heading_text);`

Comment: yes that would be right

Answer (score 0):

```js
elems = $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');
heading_text = ' some text';
elems.each(function(){
  text = $(this).text();
  $(this).text(text + heading_text);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>h1</h1>
<h2>h2</h2>
<h3>h3</h3>
<h4>h4</h4>
<h5>h5</h5>
<h6>h6</h6>
```

Comment: No need for .each with .text as jquery [has an overload](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) for that: https://jsfiddle.net/782uLesc/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.text(function)` overload](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) to append text, however this will replace any html within the header. The alternative is to `.append()` new content to each header.

As jQuery works on collections, there's no need for any loops:

```js
var heading_text = '$heading_text';

$('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').append(" " + heading_text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>H1 <i>italic</i></h1>
<h3>H3</h3>
```

Same, but using `.text()`

```js
var heading_text = '$heading_text';

$('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').text((i, txt) => txt + " " + heading_text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>H1 <i>italic</i></h1>
<h3>H3</h3>
```